# How to allow a-z 0-9 and '+' in a string and remove all others?

Tags: regex, replace, preg-replace

How to allow a-z 0-9, 'space' and 'plus' in a string and remove all other characters?

My string is:

> RIOT☩ DANNY/DA'ZE-U+S ☩ SATURDAY ☩ MAY 18TH ☩ SIMONS

can any body help me?

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i'm not sure whether i understand your question correctly...

do you want to remove all characters that are not allowed?

then replace "[^a-z 0-9+]" by ""

Comment: OP asked for space too. add `/s` also

Comment: allow characters are only a-z 0-9 plus space and apostrophe, i want to remove not allowed comparators.

Comment: @user2273162 the basic pattern has been given, you just need to extend it to fit your requirements.